# web scraping vba "Object variable or with block variable not set error" and browser crash

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

so I try to scrape data from multiple websites into excel. I think the code is working well in theory though I am having "Object variable or with block variable not set error".

The first problem that I face is that sometimes it loops perfectly from 2 to 10 and inserts every bit of data, but sometimes I get error and see that only 1 or 2 rows of data is inserted. I really could not figure out what might be the reason at this point.

Second, this is some sort of a demo code. I am only using a small batch of data and looping trough it. My real aim is to find a way to enable web scraping up to 100 rows without crashing my computer or browser. Would it be a better if I convert my code into XMLHTTP type scraping, if so how can I do it.

Thanks in Advance

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim iexp As Object
    Dim firstname(1 To 10), lastname(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim mm(1 To 10), dd(1 To 10), yyyy(1 To 10) As Integer
    Dim PhoneNumber(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim Address(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim HomeValue(1 To 10) As Variant


    Dim i As Integer



        For i = 2 To 10

        'get variables from excel sheet1 and search on peoplefinders.com

                firstname(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
                lastname(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
                mm(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
                dd(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
                yyyy(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value

                Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                ie.Visible = True
                ie.Height = 1000
                ie.Width = 1000
                ie.navigate ("http://www.peoplefinders.com/peoplesearch/searchresults?search=People&fn=" & firstname(i) & "&mn=&ln=" & lastname(i) & "&city=&state=&age=&dobmm=" & mm(i) & "&dobdd=" & dd(i) & "&doby=" & yyyy(i))

                Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
                Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

                Set Doc = ie.document

          'get elements and insert into cells in sheet 1

               PhoneNumber(i) = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
               Address(i) = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText

               Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value = PhoneNumber(i)
               Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value = Address(i)

          'modify address for next search

               a = Split(Address(i), " ")
               b = Join(a, "-")

          'search home value on zillow.com

               Set iexp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                iexp.Visible = True
                iexp.Height = 1000
                iexp.Width = 1000
                iexp.navigate ("http://www.zillow.com/homes/" & b & "_rb/")

                Do While iexp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
                Dim Doc2 As HTMLDocument

                Set Doc2 = iexp.document

               iexp.navigate ("http://www.zillow.com/homes/" & b & "_rb/")

          'insert home value into cells in sheet 1

               HomeValue(i) = Doc2.getElementsByClassName("home-summary-row")(1).getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText

               Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value = HomeValue(i)



        Next


    End Sub
```

Comment: Check the ready state as well as busy, and each time you navigate. You navigate check, then navigate again and don't get the document 2nd time

Comment: I believe you are encountering a timing issue where sometimes the response has not completed yet. Yes, using XMLDOC or IE. What I do is wait for the State to = 4; check the length of the response to see if less than good return via 'lSize = Len(IE.Document.body.innerhtml)'; I search for a known value and if not found, wait maybe a second and try again. You don't mention where the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

XHR request to list all results off first results page. You would use this inside a loop to access different results pages.

Requires references to `HTML Object Library` and `Microsoft XML library`. The `XMLHTTP60` is specific to Excel 2016. You may need to adapt to your version, for example, drop the 60 from the end.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Const URL As String = "https://www.peoplefinders.com/peoplesearch/searchresults?search=People&fn=Je&mn=&ln=Bloggs&city=&state=AL&age=&dobmm=&dobdd=&doby="
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim hTables As Object, hTable As Object
    Set hTables = html.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each hTable In hTables
        WriteTable hTable, GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, ws
    Next hTable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal columNum As Long) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, R As Long, C As Long, tBody As Object
    R = startRow
    With ws
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                R = R + 1
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                C = 1
                For Each td In tCell             'DispHTMLElementCollection
                    .Cells(R, C).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                    C = C + 1
                Next td
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```

You can loop through pages, for an individual search, by adding the page number onto the end of URL string e.g.

```
https://www.peoplefinders.com/peoplesearch/searchresults?fn=Je&ln=Bloggs&state=AL&search=People&StartPage=2
```

You can get the number of pages to loop with

```
Dim a As Object, numPages As Long
Set a = html.querySelectorAll("a.pageslinks.PaginationLinks")
numPages = a(a.Length - 1).innerText
```

So that would determine when to stop looping results pages for a particular search.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed ou by Kerem Turgutlu, checking if Busy is usually not enough, you've got to check readystate as well. Here is how I do it:

```
Sub WaitBrowser(browser As Object)
     Do While browser.Busy
           DoEvents
     Loop
     Do While browser.readyState <> 4
           DoEvents
     Loop
End Sub
```

I then call `WaitBrowser IE` after each navigation (where `IE` is my `InternetExplorer.Application` object), before meddling with the document elements.

As for other methods, whenever possible, for the sake of eficiency and predictability I prefer to send HTTP messages directly using the API (I usually go with WinHTTP, but it is possible also with XMLHTTP or winInet, I believe). Two notable exceptions: 1) I want to direct the user to the browser during or after processing, or 2) there's complex scripting involved in finding out what to send to get the desired data (in that case it's easier to let the browser do its job).

Here is an example adapted from a recent project (no error checking):

```
Function FindLink() As String
    Dim Request as Object
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Request.Open "GET", "http://example.com/pagewithinfo"
    Request.Send
    Dim resp as String
    resp = Request.ResponseText
    'create html tree with response
    Dim h As Object
    Set h = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    h.body.innerHTML = respA
    'get the info
    FindLink = h.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("a")(0).GetAttribute("href")
    Set h = Nothing
    Set Request = Nothing 
End Function
```